# Is it possible to make a np.meshgrid from a pre-existing matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, interpolation

To summarize my problem, I have a document with a couple million lines of values. My goal is to put these lines in a matrix, and be able to interpolate any value based on the matrix values. I already have half of this problem done, as I can make it into a matrix. The code I'm using for the matrix part is the following:

```py
def matrix(arr2):
    counter=0
    arr=np.loadtxt(arr2,skiprows=11)
    m=np.zeros(shape=[360,294,278]) 
    for i in range(360): #Range of x
        for j in range(294): #Range of y
            for k in range(278): #Range of Z
                m[i][j][k]=arr[counter] 
                counter+=1
    return m
```

This code works fine. The problem is interpolating. The code I found I could use for this is scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator. The problem is that it's not working with my code. The only real difference I could think about was the fact that in the example they use np.meshgrid.
The example code in the wiki for RegularGridInterpolator was the following:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
def f(x, y, z):
    return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z
x = np.linspace(1, 4, 11)
y = np.linspace(4, 7, 22)
z = np.linspace(7, 9, 33)
xg, yg ,zg = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True)
data = f(xg, yg, zg)
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), data)
pts = np.array([[2.1, 6.2, 8.3], [3.3, 5.2, 7.1]])
print(my_interpolating_function(pts))
```

This code works perfectly fine.
There are two solutions to this problem that I've thought of. Either I can change my base code to a meshgrid, or I have to re-make my code but this time make the matrix using np.meshgrid instead of np.zeros.

I'd rather not remake my code, so I was wondering if anyone could provide me with any insight.
Thanks.

Comment: Look at `xg, yg ,zg`.  Those are just `x,y,z` with some reshaping, so they broadcast together.

Comment: As an aside, you can make the `matrix` function run a lot faster if you replace the whole for loop with `m = arr.reshape((360,294,278))`.